# bootstrap wordpress navmenu

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have to build a WordPress theme based on Twitter Bootstrap.

For now I've some issue on the Navigation Bar.
The problem is that the html classes provided by WordPress (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes) are not, obviously, the same as Bootstrap.
Wrapping the wp_nav_menu in a div with class 'navbar-inner' seems to be not enough...
it takes the apparence of the navmenu but still the multilevel doesn't work.

Is there any library or php class to help me integrate the nice and candy Twitter Bootstrap NavMenu into a WordPress theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to write a custom Walker to support multilevel.

here's the doc: 
http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Nav_Menus/Walker_Nav_Menu.html

You can start from this Walker I wrote some time ago:
http://www.emanueletessore.com/bootstrap-navbar-under-wordpress/

Actually it manages multilevel and dividers.